# Как мне между слов вставить переменную?

Tags: javascript

Как мне между слов вставить переменную?

```
style="down:[сюда переменную]px"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
style = `down:${сюда_переменную}px`;
```

---

```
style = "down:" + сюда_переменную + "px";
```